# Función Javascript con un for... of para recorrer un array que se va llenando a medida que el usuario introduce datos, no funciona de manera adecuada

Tags: javascript, funciones, bucle-for, condiciones

En este código, hay una variable showGender que posee una función anónima y dentro un for... of para recorrer un array de libros que va registrando el usuario.

Al finalizar el registro de libros y querer inicializar la búsqueda de alguno de los mismos, el código referente a showGender lanza un mensaje de error del segundo condicional donde dice que no existe ese género y luego seguidamente si muestra la búsqueda de dicho genero y ofrece el resultado correctamente. No sé por qué ocurre ésto.

```js
class Book {
        constructor(title, author, year, gender) {
            this.title = title;
            this.author = author;
            this.year = year;
            this.gender = gender;
    
        }
        bookInfo(){
            return `El nombre del Libro es ${this.title} es un libro de ${this.gender} el cual fue escrito por por el Señor(a) ${this.author} en el año ${this.year}`
        }
    
        getGender (){
            return this.gender;
        }
    
    }
    let Books = [];
    
    while(Books.length < 2){
        let title = prompt("Por favor ingresar el Nombre del Libro que deseas registrar:");
        let author = prompt("Por favor ingresar el Autor del Libro que deseas registrar:");
        let year = prompt("Por favor ingresar el Año del Libro que deseas registrar:");
        let gender = prompt("Por favor ingresar el Genero del Libro que deseas registrar:").toLowerCase();
    
        if(title != "" && 
            author != "" && 
            !isNaN(year) && 
            year.length == 4 && 
            (gender == "aventura" || gender == "terror" || gender == "fantasia")); 
    
            Books.push(new Book(title, author, year, gender));
    } 
    
    const showGender = () => {
        const gender = prompt("Ingresar el Genero del libro que desas buscar: ");
        for (const book of Books){
            if (book.getGender() == gender) {
                alert(`Los Libros encontrados son;\n1- ${book.bookInfo()}`);
            }else{
                alert(`Lo sentimos pero de ese genero no tenemos libros disponibles`)
            }
        } 
    }
    
    const showAllBooks = () =>{
        console.log(Books[0]);
    }
    
    showAllBooks();
    showGender();
```

Comment: Lo que pasa es que por cada libro del cual su género coincida va a salir la alerta de éxito. Por cada uno que no coincida, va a salir la alerta de fallo

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te recomendaría es hacer un filtrado con [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) para filtar tus libros por género. Si la linfitud es 0, ya sabes que no hay libros de ese género. De lo contrario, puedes mostrarlos mediante un [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
class Book {
  constructor(title, author, year, gender) {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.year = year;
    this.gender = gender;

  }
  bookInfo() {
    return `El nombre del Libro es ${this.title} es un libro de ${this.gender} el cual fue escrito por por el Señor(a) ${this.author} en el año ${this.year}`
  }

  getGender() {
    return this.gender;
  }

}
let Books = [];

while (Books.length < 2) {
  let title = prompt("Por favor ingresar el Nombre del Libro que deseas registrar:");
  let author = prompt("Por favor ingresar el Autor del Libro que deseas registrar:");
  let year = prompt("Por favor ingresar el Año del Libro que deseas registrar:");
  let gender = prompt("Por favor ingresar el Genero del Libro que deseas registrar:").toLowerCase();

  if (title != "" &&
    author != "" &&
    !isNaN(year) &&
    year.length == 4 &&
    (gender == "aventura" || gender == "terror" || gender == "fantasia"));

  Books.push(new Book(title, author, year, gender));
}

const showGender = () => {
  const gender = prompt("Ingresar el Genero del libro que desas buscar: ");
  const filtered_books = Books.filter(book => book.getGender() === gender);
  if (filtered_books.length === 0) {
    return alert(`Lo sentimos pero de ese genero no tenemos libros disponibles`);
  }
  filtered_books.forEach((book, idx) =>
    alert(`Los Libros encontrados son;\n${idx+1}- ${book.bookInfo()}`)
  );
}

const showAllBooks = () => {
  Books.forEach((book, idx) =>
    console.log(`${idx+1}.- ${book.bookInfo()}`)
  );
}


showAllBooks();
showGender();
```

Answer (score 0):

> En tu codigo si ingresas una de las posibilidades por ejemplo: primero
> **aventura** y luego *terror* y luego buscas genero *terror* al comparar en el array  da la alerta lo sentimos... al ser distinto
> aventura a terror y tambien te  comunica que **encontro** a terror  Al
> utilizar en showGender()  book of Books no solo comparara  a un solo
> libro registrado en el array de Books  con el genero a buscar   Es el
> motivo por el cual no hace lo que queres y por lo cual hay que usar
> por ejemplo filter lo cual te da una solucion limpia y declarativa de
> facil lectura  como ya te lo indicaron o agregar una comparacion
> adicional para alertar cuando no tenemos a ese genero disponible como
> en el siguiente codigo pero el cual resulta imperativo

```js
class Book {
         constructor(title, author, year, gender) {
             this.title = title;
             this.author = author;
             this.year = year;
             this.gender = gender;
     
         }
         bookInfo(){
             return `El nombre del Libro es ${this.title} es un libro de ${this.gender} el cual fue escrito por por el Señor(a) ${this.author} en el año ${this.year}`
         }
     
         getGender (){
             return this.gender;
         }
     
     }
     let Books = [];
     
     while(Books.length < 2){
         let title = prompt("Por favor ingresar el Nombre del Libro que deseas registrar:");
         let author = prompt("Por favor ingresar el Autor del Libro que deseas registrar:");
         let year = prompt("Por favor ingresar el Año del Libro que deseas registrar:");
         let gender = prompt("Por favor ingresar el Genero del Libro que deseas registrar:").toLowerCase();
     
         if(title != "" && 
             author != "" && 
             !isNaN(year) && 
             year.length == 4 && 
             (gender === "aventura" || gender === "terror" || gender === "fantasia"))
             { Books.push(new Book(title, author, year, gender));}
             else{
               alert(`los libros deben ser de tipo aventura,terror,fantasia`);
             }

            
     
            
     } 
     
     const showGender = () => {
         const gender = prompt("Ingresar el Genero del libro que desas buscar: ");
         console.log('......>',gender); console.log('......>',);
         let i=0;
        let encontrado=''
         if(i<= Books.length){
         for (const book of Books){
         
             console.log('......>',book);console.log('......>',book.gender)
             if (book.gender === gender) {
           console.log(book.gender);
           encontrado=gender
            console.log('encontrado:',encontrado)
                 alert(`Los Libros encontrados son;\n1- ${book.bookInfo()}`);
                // null, alongside false, 0, '', undefined, NaN, is a falsy valu
             }
         }
         ++i
         } if(encontrado !=gender){
                alert(`Lo sentimos pero de ese genero no tenemos libros disponibles`)
         }
          
     }
     
     const showAllBooks = () =>{
         console.log(Books[0]);
     }
     
     showAllBooks();
     showGender();
```